# Why can't @UniqueConstraint find column from super class?

Tags: java, jpa, unique-constraint

I have this superclass that implements common properties and a subclass that inherits from it:

```
@MappedSuperClass
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public abstract class BaseEntity extends Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    protected String id;

    @Setter
    protected String orgId;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraints(columnNames = {"org_id", "name"}))
public class SimpleEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;
}
```

This gives me a runtime error with JPA/Hibernate complaining that the "org_id" column cannot be found on the SimpleClass table. However, the column does exist in the table when I look in the database.

If I change the unique constraint annotation to the below then it works:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraints(columnNames = {"orgId", "name"}))
```

While I'm glad I found a workaround, I am trying to understand why. Have others seen this too? Do I indeed have to refer to the Java property name for inherited properties instead of their actual column name?

Comment: Well, the default mapping for a field named "orgId" if to be mapped to a column named "orgId", not "org_id". So you need to tell Hibernate that the column for the field orgId must be org_id: `@Column(name="org_id")`. When asking about an exception, always, always post the complete stack trace of the exception. Paraphrasing the error message just makes the problem harder to indentify.

Comment: Thanks! @JBNizet if you post that as the answer then I tap to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default mapping for a field named "orgId" is to be mapped to a column named "orgId", not "org_id".

So you need to tell Hibernate that the column for the field `orgId` must be `org_id`:

```
 @Column(name = "org_id")
```